# The generation algorithm of letters from the Latin alphabet?

Tags: python, django, algorithm, python-3.x, django-views

Can someone help me to create algorithm. I have model `"Function"` with field `"symbol"`.

When user create new function object system need to create automatically value of `"symbol"` field from letters of the English alphabet. Right now I  did only from A to Z and without repeating record field value.

**For example**:

```
A
B
-
Z
AA
AB
-
AZ
BA
BB
-
ZZ
AAA
etc.
```

**models.py:**

```
class Function(models.Model):
    id= models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    symbol = models.TextField ()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
if form.is_valid():
   for i in string.ascii_uppercase:  # (A-Z)
         if not Function.objects.filter(symbol=i, project=project_code).exists():
             function = form.save(commit=False)
             function.symbol = i
             function.save()
             break
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the built-in functions do the boring work for you.

I think you will do much better with [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  Create the generator and just call **next()** Whenever you need the next combination.  If you want to start with 1-letter strings and work up from there, then include space as the first element of your alphabet; when you grab a new label, **strip()** the white space out before applying it.

Comment: Thank you for this information. As I understand from `itertools.product()` we need to set number of position (n-letter string). I mean `repeat` argument. What I need to do if I need infinite number? Can you show your idea with example pls I am little bit comfused.

Comment: If you need an arbitrary size, then I suggest that you write a wrapper generator: one that starts with **repeat==1** and loops through higher numbers as needed.  However, I suspect that in reality, you can set an upper limit sufficiently large to cover your actual needs.